# Alternative axioms of the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers

The common axioms of the real numbers are stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers). I'm trying to formulate alternative axioms that are closer to the construction of the real numbers based on Cauchy sequences. Because this construction uniquely determines the real numbers, I would think that the following axioms are sufficient to determine them. However, are they all necessary? Are there easier or more elegant formulations?

**Definition:** $(\Bbb R, +,\cdot,\le)$ is a model of the real numbers if

1. $(\Bbb R, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
2. $\le$ is a total ordering on $\Bbb R$, and (for all $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$)

   - $x\le y$ implies $x+z\le y+z$
   - If $0\le x,y$, then $0\le x\cdot y$.
3. All Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$ are convergent with respect to $\lvert\cdot\rvert\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by
   $$
   \lvert x\rvert = \begin{cases}
   x & \text{if $0\le x$}\\
   -x& \text{if $0\not\le x$}
   \end{cases}
   $$
4. There exists a subset $\Bbb Q$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $(\Bbb Q,+,\cdot)$ is a model for the rational numbers.
5. If $M$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ containing $\Bbb Q$, and if $M$ is sequence-closed with respect to $\lvert\cdot\rvert$, then $M = \Bbb R$.

Comment: Are you trying to classify the Real numbers uniquely?

Comment: Well, yes, to reformulate a set of axioms that only the real numbers satisfy.

Comment: Your property (4) is automatically satisfied as a consequence of (1) and (2).

Comment: Your 4th axiom is quite complicated and is certainly far removed from first-order logic. Its complexity makes it less elegant than other formulations.

Comment: Nice question. Note that every field of characteristic $0$ includes a copy of the rational numbers. This allows you to weaken axiom 4 considerably.

Comment: @Rory: If one wants to characterize the real numbers _uniquely_, then one cannot make do with first-order axioms -- thanks to the Löwenheim-Skolem theorems, every first-order theory that has an infinite model has many non-isomorphic models.

Comment: Note that if you want to discuss the countable model $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$, you can do this uniquely in the language $L_{\omega_1\omega}$, but actually describing the (real) reals is much harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the following theorem that appears in chapter 30 (p. 593) of Calculus by Spivak:

If $F$ is a complete ordered field, then $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Spivak defines an ordered field to be (quoting now from p. 573) a field $F$ (with operations $+$ and $\cdot$)
together with a certain subset $P$ of $F$ (the "positive" elements) with the following properties:

1. For all $a$ in $F$, one and only one of the following is true: (i) $a = 0$, (ii) $a$ is in $P$ , (iii) $-a$ is in $P$.
2. If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then $a + b$ is in $P$.
3. If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then $a \cdot b$ is in $P$.

He defines a complete ordered field (on p. 574) to be an ordered field in which every nonempty set which is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Comment: So $\Bbb Q$ is not necessary for the formulation?

Comment: No: A square number cannot be negative in an ordered field, so the characteristic must be zero, hence it contains $\Bbb Q$ as the subfield generated by $1$.